# Image cropping and thumb creation

Tags: php, image, web

I need to help a friend to make his own artistic gallery. 
I already have all done, but I need a tool/plugin/script to make him independent from me in uploading his own images. My gallery needs two images: a cropped one of a certain proportion (so i need him to crop by himself in an uploading page) and a thumb one (I want this be done automatically).

Do you know an easy way to do this? What would you do?

Thanks.

Comment: use this answer for image resizing and thumbnail creation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069981/image-getting-stretched/10070222#10070222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i use this in all of my projects - http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm
Works perfectly with upload files and with files that's already on the system.

Can do many things convert, resize and work on uploaded images in many ways, apply effects, add labels, watermarks and reflections and other image editing features.

Easy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to be having heavy traffic to start - look at http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/ which can create your resized images on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You need only GD library, function imagecopyresampled will suit you. PHP manual has really good example code for thumbnail creation http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php
You will need just to create exceptions for different file formats

Answer (score 1):

```
function create_jpeg_thumbnail($thumbImageName,$imgSrc,$thumbDirectory,$thumbnail_width,$thumbnail_height) { //$imgSrc is a FILE - Returns an image resource.
        $thumbDirectory = trim($thumbDirectory);
        $imageSourceExploded = explode('/', $imgSrc);
        $imageName = $imageSourceExploded[count($imageSourceExploded)-1];
        $imageDirectory = str_replace($imageName, '', $imgSrc);
        $filetype = explode('.',$imageName);
        $filetype = strtolower($filetype[count($filetype)-1]);

        //getting the image dimensions 
        list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imgSrc);  


        //$myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc);
        if ($filetype == 'jpg') {
            $myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
        } else
        if ($filetype == 'jpeg') {
            $myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
        } else
        if ($filetype == 'png') {
            $myImage = imagecreatefrompng("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
        } else
        if ($filetype == 'gif') {
            $myImage = imagecreatefromgif("$imageDirectory/$imageName");
        }

        $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

        if ($thumbnail_width/$thumbnail_height > $ratio_orig) {
           $new_height = $thumbnail_width/$ratio_orig;
           $new_width = $thumbnail_width;
        } else {
           $new_width = $thumbnail_height*$ratio_orig;
           $new_height = $thumbnail_height;
        }

        $x_mid = $new_width/2;  //horizontal middle
        $y_mid = $new_height/2; //vertical middle

        $process = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_width), round($new_height));

        imagecopyresampled($process, $myImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $process, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);
        //$thumbImageName = 'thumb_'.get_random_no().'.jpeg';
        $destination = $thumbDirectory=='' ? $thumbImageName : $thumbDirectory."/".$thumbImageName;
        imagejpeg($thumb, $destination, 100);
        return $thumbImageName;
    }
```